# Is there a way to comment out a CSS style in a stylesheet so it is only read by a particular browser (IE, FF, or Chrome)

Tags: css

for instance:

I have a min-height on an element:

```
#myElement
{
    min-height: 800px;
    min-height: 799px;
}
```

and in IE I want it to only interpret the min-height:799px;

Comment: why not use conditional statements ? and media queries for Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use Conditional Statements and create a stylesheet just for IE. A Google Search will bring back many results but I find this to be very useful:

http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

If you look at the bottom of that article, it is possible to use hacks (although I don't recommend them) to target specific IE version within the SAME stylesheet.

With FireFox you can use the moz prefix like so:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #myElement {
        min-height: 800px;
    }
}
```

I'm sure there would be ones for Opera, Safari etc too - just search for browser specific conditional statements in Google :)